# MVC open new page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I would like to open new window for a defined URL from the Controller code.

Can this be done?

Controller code:

```
string url = $"{userResponseLink}&ID={ID}&name={encrypt_after}&type={type}";
Redirect(url);
```

and I need open a new page, so I tried:

```
 Response.Write($"<script>window.open( '{url}' , '-blank' );</script>");
```

but it doesn't work.

How can I open new window from an MVC Controller?

Comment: You have `-blank` instead of `_blank`. Re: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Comment: still can not work

Comment: Is your `url` valid?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2677072/asp-net-mvc-what-is-the-correct-way-to-redirect-to-pages-actions-in-mvc

Comment: Response.Write is actually going to output the javascript, not execute it. include more code, what are you trying to do?  Also there are no "controls" in mvc.

Comment: my url is another website. I put the url into google browser, it cant work.
I just want to open the url webstie in another page.

Comment: Your question totally does not relate to MVC. Perhaps you could post more code, then we could help you better, else it will be downvoted and remove from so

Comment: Redirect is MVC Controller() funtion.   protected internal virtual RedirectResult Redirect(string url);  but it can not open new page. I just want to open new page.

Comment: Well, you can't simply passing JS through `Response.Redirect` as webforms does. Of course you can use anchor tag with `Url.Action` and `target="_blank"` attribute, but still I didn't understand what you exactly want to do.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto that's why he needs to provide more code, but seem like he refuses to ~~