# need to redirect to another page if user is authenticated but unauthorized in as.net

Tags: asp.net-core

i have a page and i need a specific user to enter this page ,if this user is  unauthorized it should redirect him to a registration page so he can be authorized.
how can i redirect him? what code should i write in Index function?
this  [Authorize(Roles ="Manager,UserGold")] just don't let him to enter page i want to redirect him

```
 [Authorize(Roles ="Manager,UserGold")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string search)
        {
           }
```

Comment: See this prior Q: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2677072/asp-net-mvc-what-is-the-correct-way-to-redirect-to-pages-actions-in-mvc

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ASP.NET MVC: What is the correct way to redirect to pages/actions in MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2677072/asp-net-mvc-what-is-the-correct-way-to-redirect-to-pages-actions-in-mvc)

Answer (score 0):

```
  if (!User.IsInRole("UserGold")) { 
            return RedirectToAction("register", "GoldMenu");
        }
```